# How to add toggleBoldface option to a UITextView in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I wish to add toggleBoldface, toggleItalics and toggleUnderline to the editting options of a UITextView. How can this be done? Preferrably in Swift please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enable the text view's `allowsEditingTextAttributes` property.

Comment: I never realised it was this easy. I was almost done with doing it by adding a custom UIMenuItem. Dumb! Thanks maddy!

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept answers that solve your questions.

Comment: I was waiting for SO to let me do that

Comment: @rmaddy: Can I have bold and italic in the same time?

Comment: @el.severo you can just select both of them one after another and everything you type after that will be in bold as well as italics

Comment: @rmaddy: that's strange. I've did small test and seems it works only with *`Standard / System`*. Do you know how to handle this with custom font?

Comment: @el.severo Sounds like you should post your own question. Be sure to include relevant code and details about the issue.

Answer (score 4):

For those who came here because they enabled `Allows Editing Attributes` in IB but don't see the BIU `UIMenu` in the app: apparently that checkbox only activates attribute editing for the pre-defined string displayed in IB, but not in the actual `UITextView` presented to the user. You still have to enable the `allowsEditingTextAttributes` property somewhere in your code.

Comment: I spent some time just trying to find out this answer.  Thank you!!  I think this should be the correct answer because it is detailed much better than the currently accepted answer!